# Unable to retrieve passwords from WebLogic configuration

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I have the following code in a web service deployed on WebLogic 12.2.1. It will retrieve the keystore file name and password from WebLogic configuration.

```
    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
    MBeanServer server = (MBeanServer) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jmx/runtime");
    ObjectName runtime = new ObjectName("com.bea:Name=MLMAppSrv01,Type=Server");
    Object keyStoreFileName = server.getAttribute(runtime, "CustomIdentityKeyStoreFileName");
    Object keyStorePassPhrase = server.getAttribute(runtime, "CustomIdentityKeyStorePassPhrase");
```

It is able to retrieve the keystore file name, but when it tries to retrieve the password, the following exception is thrown.

```
[Management:141302]Access not allowed for Subject: principals=[], on resource Server, action: read, target CustomIdentityKeyStorePassPhrase.
```

Under the domain's security, I have already enabled "Clear Text Credential Access Enabled".

What else could be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any Username in your code. With weblogic user or some other admin user you should retrieve the password. Otherwise it will not allow you to access the password.

If you want to use some other user than weblogic then make sure that you add that user to Administrator group.

Comment: The WebLogic server is started as a service using a Windows login ID with administrator rights (lets call this ID "X"). To login the WebLogic console, I used an ID (let's call this ID "Y"). Is the user name that I need to pass in my code "Y", the same ID that I can login WebLogic console? How do I do so in my codes?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the credentials as given in below sample code.

```
Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
   properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                  "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
   // NOTE: The port number of the server is provided in the next line,
   //       followed by the userid and password on the next two lines.
   properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:9001");
   properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "weblogic");
   properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "welcome1");
   try {
       ctx = new InitialContext(properties);
   } catch (NamingException ne) {
       ne.printStackTrace(System.err);
       System.exit(0);
   }
```

Comment: I need to access the keystore in my codes and so i need to get the password. Rather than hard coding the password in my code, I thought of retrieving it from Weblogic configuration. Now your suggestion is for hardcoding the weblogic password in the code instead. It doesn't seem to solve my problem of not hardcoding passwords.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve password of keystore or Weblogic domain ?

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve key store password using code. But to do so i need to retrieve weblogic password now. No hardcoding of passwords are allowed in codes. You are hardcoding the weblogic password in the codes.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding password pass it as an Argument while executing or read it from user.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Let me explain. My codes must work in a production environment in a web service. All passwords are securely stored (such as the keystore), they are all unknown to the program. There is no intervention from users and also not possible since my codes works in a web service. If I am able to pass in a password, I would have passed the keystore password in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not authenticated and therefore get no access to restricted ressources. Add the annotation @RunAs("WEBLOGIC") to your class  and configure it in the WEB-INF/weblogic-ejb-jar.xml

(Where WEBLOGIC is the name of a user with administrator rights in the Weblogic console, the default Admin Account is even named weblogic)

Your class should look like this:

```
@Stateless
@RunAs("WEBLOGIC")
public class SomeService {
// ...
}
```

Contents of the weblogic-ejb-jar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-ejb-jar>
   <run-as-role-assignment>
     <role-name>WEBLOGIC</role-name>
     <run-as-principal-name>weblogic</run-as-principal-name>
   </run-as-role-assignment>
</weblogic-ejb-jar>
```

Comment: If my weblogic user name is "wlsadm", then what do I put? Should I specify "wlsadm" or WEBLOGIC for @RunAs? And what about the weblogic-ejb-jar.xml?

Comment: just replace "weblogic" with wlsadm then (all occurences for easier reading). The weblogic-ejb-jar.xml should be in your WEB-INF Folder, if not create it. The application only needs it to know which role to use. Since you are using WebService, you have a Web-Application, right?

Comment: I finally tried your solution today, but it still doesn't work. My weblogic administration ID is "wlsysad". I put @RunAs("wlsysad") at the top of the web service class as you suggested. Then I created WEB-INF\weblogic-ejb-jar.xml with the content as you suggested. For <role-name> and <run-as-principal-name>, I put both values as "wlsysad".

Comment: There are actually two @RunAs annotation. One is from javax.annotation.security.RunAs. The other from is from weblogic.jws.security.RunAs, which is deprecated. I am using javax.annotation.security.RunAs.

Comment: javax.annotation.security.RunAs is correct. Do you still get the same Exception? If yes, your bean has to be an ejb bean. That's why my example has the @Stateless (from javax.ejb.Stateless) Annotation.

Comment: It's not an EJB bean. My web service class extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application. And yes, I am still getting the same exception.

Comment: That makes sense, @ RunAs only works with EJB beans. You can try adding @ javax.ejb.Stateless to your web service class, that should not do any harm. But I don't know if that will work. Unfortunately we reached the end of my knowledge :(

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar case, which my jersey code needs to get the keys from the keystore programmatically in WLS. No EJB settings are required. You just need to define the web.xml and weblogic.xml properly.

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>{jersey webservice class}</servlet-name>
    <run-as>
        <role-name>admRole</role-name>
    </run-as>        
</servlet>

<security-role>
    <role-name>admRole</role-name>
</security-role>
```

weblogic.xml:

```
<run-as-role-assignment>
    <role-name>admRole</role-name>
    <run-as-principal-name>wlsadm</run-as-principal-name>
</run-as-role-assignment>
```